# Save variable format on file in ansible

Tags: ansible-2.x

In ansible, I'm would like to store a variable in his format in host_vars file; to be more clear as possible

i would like to schedule a playbook to update my inventory

**  blockinfile:
path: "/mypath/host_vars/{{ inventory_hostname | upper }}"
block: |
ansible_user: "{{ usernamevariable }}"
ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ userpasswordvariable }}"
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
ansible_winrm_transport: ntlm
ansible_port: 5985

**

but on host_var file i found the value of my variable and not the text write as show

How i cand do it ?

Regards

Diego

i've tried to use ' or ` character before variable without success

Answer (score 0):

i've solved do so

```
            ansible_user: "{{ ' '.join(('{{', 'usernamevariable', '}}' )) }}"
            ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ ' '.join(('{{', 'userpasswordvariable ', '}}' )) }}"
```